# Ruby instance variable

Tags: ruby

```
class Polygon
  attr_accessor :sides
  @sides = 10
end
```

When I try to access

```
puts Polygon.new.sides # => nil
```

I get nil. How to access sides?
What is wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, downvotes. Well, +1 from me. JVK gave an example, showed what he tried, and the desired output is obvious.

Comment: Don't understand the down votes, its a good question

Comment: @DigitalRoss I am a newbie and learning Ruby for few days now. And it seems few people think stackoverflow is not for newbie to ask question.

Comment: Thank you all to answer this foobar question for a ruby newbie :)

Comment: It was a perfectly good question, keep asking. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ruby class definitions are just executable code, when you say `@sides = 10` in the context of a class definition, you're defining that on `Polygon` (not instances of Polygon):

```
class Polygon
  attr_accessor :sides
  @sides = 10
end

Polygon.instance_variables
# => [:@sides]
```

You probably want to set the number of sides on the *instances* of Polygon, from the initializer:

```
class Polygon
  attr_accessor :sides

  def initialize(sides)
    @sides = sides
  end
end 

Polygon.new(10).sides
# => 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
def initialize
  @sides = 10
end
```

By assigning to `@sides` at the class level, you created a *class instance variable* rather than an *instance variable* of the object you created with `#new`.

In this case, you have an attribute of a given `Polygon,` but if it was actually an attribute of the class (like *author* or *copyright* or something) then you could reference it via the `@whatever` syntax *if* you were in a *class method,* created with `def self.something ... end`.

Answer (score 1):

The attr_accessor, in short defines two methods.

```
def sides
end

def sides=
end
```

To get the value of the sides which have mentioned here, you need to init them in

```
def initialize
  @sides = 10
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This exact question (even uses the same example code you have), is answered on [railstips.org](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).